# Python: generate a random 2d array of integers from given sums of its rows and columns

Tags: python

Is there any way to generate a 2d array with a fixed sum of each row and each column?

**for example**

TargetArray = 3 rows and 4 columns

Sum of Each row = [30, 20, 30]

Sum of Each column = [23, 10, 27, 20]

I was trying to solve this a lot of days with no result

Comment: use numpy sum function with axis=0 or 1?

Comment: I suspect this might be quite hard. There's an obvious integer linear or constraint programming formulation for this problem, but that probably doesn't scale well. What's your use case? How large will your matrices be, and how often do you need them?

Comment: @GeneByun he needs to "unsum" them

Comment: @NielsWouda [easy peasy](https://pastebin.com/raw/GNxKHZFq)

Comment: @Pychopath ah yes, certainly! I implicitly imposed that all elements >= 0, because that's the algorithmically interesting problem (but might not be what OP needs, since they do not mention this restriction). If one allows negatives it's relatively easy to construct such matrices, as you have shown.

Comment: @NielsWouda Yes, that would've been a more interesting/challenging question. I might try that later as well. That also [exists at LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-valid-matrix-given-row-and-column-sums/) (though with the guarantee that a valid matrix exists), so if someone wants non-negative and knows that a valid matrix exists, they can find plenty solutions there.

Answer (score 1):

(Temporary note until they hopefully unvandalize their question: They added the "random" and "positive" requirements later, after this answer.)

Simple solution:

```
     23 10 27 20

30  -27 10 27 20
20   20  0  0  0
30   30  0  0  0
```

Code to build it:

```
R = [30, 20, 30]
C = [23, 10, 27, 20]

assert sum(R) == sum(C)
matrix = [[(0 if j else r) if i else (c if j else r+c-sum(R))
           for j, c in enumerate(C)]
          for i, r in enumerate(R)]
```

Or:

```
matrix = [[0 if i and j else
           r if i else
           c if j else
           r + c - sum(R)
           for j, c in enumerate(C)]
          for i, r in enumerate(R)]
```

Or a somewhat cute way, always building a mini-matrix of the four possibilities and picking the right one (assumes a non-empty matrix):

```
x = R[0] + C[0] - sum(R)
matrix = [[[[x, c],
            [r, 0]][i > 0][j > 0]
           for j, c in enumerate(C)]
          for i, r in enumerate(R)]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @Pychopath
But each matrix has a negative number.

I want all values to be positives if we can

Comment: @Al-MunthirS You could ask that as a new question.

Comment: @Al-MunthirS [*"If the question is reasonably clear (but maybe a little vague), but the asker just simply asked the wrong question, then correcting the question and invalidating any of the existing answers would be incorrect."*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266969/18238422).

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for that, I will return my question to orginal and ask my correct question again.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with an algorithm called Iterative Proportional Fitting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_proportional_fitting.
IPF allows it to reconstruct a non-negative matrix from row an column sum vectors.

There is a Python implementation for this, called ipfn.

```
from ipfn import ipfn
import numpy as np

seed = np.ones((3,4))
row_sum = [30, 20, 30]
column_sum = [23, 10, 27, 20]    
aggregates = [row_sum, column_sum]
dimensions = [[0], [1]]
IPF = ipfn.ipfn(seed, aggregates, dimensions, convergence_rate=1e-6)
X = IPF.iteration()

X = array([[ 8.625,  3.75 , 10.125,  7.5  ],
   [ 5.75 ,  2.5  ,  6.75 ,  5.   ],
   [ 8.625,  3.75 , 10.125,  7.5  ]])
```

By changing, the seed, you will get different results. If you require X to contain integers only, then you need to resort to an integerized version of IPF. However, as far as I know, there is no Python implementation for this.